# Wordpress Custom Field Query-Date Field

Tags: wordpress, datetime, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom field 'birthday' which displays in the format     (Ymd)    .
I want to query posts that have their month(m) field equal to the current month so I can congratulate people throughout the month.
I know that I will have to match the birthdays month part(substring?) to something like     $date = date('m');
But am not sure how to go about building the query...Thanks in advance.Cheers

Answer (score 0):

about the query should be like this

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query'     => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'birthdays',
                    'value'   => '$m',
                    'compare' => 'IN',
                ),
            ),

);
query_posts( $args );
```